# How to change the dialog and power menu text color in an android theme

Tags: android, menu, fonts, colors, themes

Okay, so I'm creating an android theme and for the life of me I cannot find out how to change the menu or dialog font color.

I've tried adding

```
    <color name="textColorPrimary">#ff503600</color>
```

to the colors.xml and referencing it as

```
    <item name="color/textColorPrimary">@color/textColorPrimary</item>
```

in the android.xml, but it doesn't seem to do anything. I've been able to research and figure out about 98% of everything I've needed up to this point, but this one has stumped me.

Basically I want to turn the default white font color into something darker so that it shows up better.

[Here's a screenshot of the power menu](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/sh/evasqzthykpj0fs/SmSq-d3Ery/pwrmn.gif)

Comment: Assuming that's a system dialog, you cannot write an app that affects the styling of a system dialog, unless you are building your own ROM mod or something.

Comment: It's a theme to use with Theme Chooser

Comment: I think if I try to reference the holo.dark it might work, gonna go research how to do that. Thanks for the tip!